# WooCommerce REST API error uploading images

Tags: php, rest, woocommerce

I'm trying to upload a product with a few images to a customer's woocommerce site, using the REST APIs.
When I try the same exact operation on my own test sites it all goes well, but when I do it there I get an "invalid JSON" error.
I'm sure the problem is in the images because when I do not send them, the upload works perfectly.
What could be causing this?

I tried changing the php.ini adding the lines:

```
max_execution_time = 300
memory_limit = 192M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
max_input_time = 300
```

but nothing changed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue (especially on local environment). It turned out that the error is related to timeout on **client side**. Try to increase the timeout of your curl/ajax/whatever.

With the PHP Client you has a convenient option to do so

```
       $client = new WC_API_Client(
            API_URL,
            CONSUMER_KEY,
            CONSUMER_SECRET,
            array(
                'debug'           => false,
                'ssl_verify' => false,
                'return_as_array' => false,
                'timeout' => 120
            )
        );
```

Also, if you're passing a remote image (woocommerce will download automatically the image from the url provided) you should check if the image actually exists, other users reported that another way of getting the error you reported is with an error (eg 404, 403...) with the image url passed.